# Traffic Compression

Tags: video, proxy, streaming

I have multiple users who are using a limited connection,

I have setup a remote proxy server using 'ziproxy', but currently it only support compression for html/images.

I would like some sort of solution to compress videos (mp4, youtube ...etc) in order to save traffic.

Are there any solution that I can install on top of ziproxy to manipulate videos & re-stream it?

Comment: Video and audio data is already highly compressed and you are unlikely to see any benefit at all by trying to pass them through ziproxy.

Comment: I know it cannot be compressed using gzip, I am looking for a solution that will let me change the video quality & sound quality on the fly i.e: if the proxy detected the mime type as being a video it will pass it through an application which would lower its quality then pass it to user.

Comment: What you are looking for is called transcoding and a quick Google shows up nothing for transcoding proxies, probably because for more than one or two users the amount of CPU time required is increasingly prohibitive.  Decoding is relatively easy, encoding is very difficult.  It's probably easier to simply block high-def streams from youtube using a more conventional proxy and restrict users to low-def streams.

Comment: The lowest def for youtube is 240p I am looking for something that would make it lower than that. I've seen a few companies advertise this feature like skyfire but they haven't provided information on how it's done.

Comment: If the real issue is that you have users with low bandwidth you might want to look into [adaptive streaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_bitrate_streaming) techniques. Those are mostly proprietary though, or hard to set up. Adobe's dynamic streaming and Apple's HTTP Live Streaming are quite popular though